# How do you setup a queue listener inside of a artemis broker?

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have a db connected JAAS implementation for my Artemis broker.  I have a topic queue that I post to which triggers the security modules in several of our apps to refetch/update our users/roles data.  I need my JAAS to do the same.  I would like to use the same topic queue to force the trigger, but I have been unable to create a queue listener inside of the broker due to a lack of a session. (The JAAS implementation is in a jar which Artemis loads).

Comment: what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: We tried setting up a listener just like you would normally on a client side, but, obviously, that did nothing.  We also tried setting up a interceptor, but they are pinged for every bit of traffic not just message traffic.  And we tried setting up a divert, which so far is the best thing we've found for this.  But it is not ideal.  Theres no transaction and no session.  We've scoured the internet but have come up with nada as of yet.

Comment: What is JASS?  Do you mean JAAS?

Comment: I can't believe I typed that several times and misspelled it every time.  Yes JAAS

Comment: Did you try creating a message listener in the JAAS module itself?  That seems to me like it would work just fine.  You might have to spawn your own thread with a retry or something if the module is initialized before the queue is available.  You also might consider using a broker plugin - http://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/broker-plugins.html.

Comment: Actually I was able find a solution to the problem.  I couldn't create a listener directly, but I was able to create a Consumer by hand which serves my purpose just fine.  I ran it in its own thread so it wouldn't block the JAAS module which is what instantiates it.  Then passed in the reload method as a lambda and voila.  Thanks for your help.